# How to debug a 'System::Threading::ThreadStart' error?

Tags: .net, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++-cli

I am working with C++/CLI (Visual C++) project in these days using MS Visual Studio 2010 professional. I have a class called `SRecognizer` which use some C# libraries. Now, it has the following code

```
r = gcnew RTMotionDetector();

Thread ^detectionThread = gcnew Thread(gcnew System::Threading::ThreadStart(this,&r->start()));
```

The `RMotionDetector` class's header is below

```
#pragma once
#include "MotionDetector.h"

ref class RTMotionDetector :
    public MotionDetector
{
public:
    RTMotionDetector(void);
    ~RTMotionDetector(void);
    void start();
    void pause();
    void stop();

private:
    VideoCapture *cam1;
};
```

When the program is run, it gives the following error

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Automated Intruder Tracking System, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 7/3/2013 1:03:49 PM.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Debug\Automated Intruder Tracking System.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
1>Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
1>ClCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>  SRecognizer.cpp
1>SRecognizer.cpp(38): error C2102: '&' requires l-value
1>SRecognizer.cpp(38): error C3350: 'System::Threading::ThreadStart' : a delegate constructor expects 2 argument(s)
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:02.19
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

As you can see, the error is with how I created the thread in `SRecognizer` which you already have the particular code above. I am fairly new to C++/CLI.

Comment: Have you corrected the missing ")" error? This one is obvious. Does it change anything more?

Comment: @JeffRSon: Thank you a lot for the reply. I corrected that issue. Now the missing l-value and other error remains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix the compiler error:

```
Thread^ detectionThread = gcnew Thread(gcnew System::Threading::ThreadStart(r, &RTMotionDetector::start));
```